# Remove a node like <nom:Hrs/> from xml with vb .net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I have a XML like this:

```html
<cfdi:Comprobante>
  <cfdi:Emisor>
  </cfdi:Emisor>
  <cfdi:Conceptos>

    <cfdi:Concepto/>

  </cfdi:Conceptos>

  <cfdi:Complemento>

    <nomina:Nomina DATO="21">

      <nomina:Percepciones>

        <nomina:Percepcion/>

      </nomina:Percepciones>

      <nomina:Incapacidades/>

      <nomina:HorasExtras/>

    </nomina:Nomina>

  </cfdi:Complemento>

</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

and need to remove the nodes:

```
      <nomina:Incapacidades/>
      <nomina:HorasExtras/>
```

and the attribute DATO="21".

I tried the next code:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(_xml2)
doc.Root.Element("nomina:Incapacidades").Remove()
doc.Root.Element("nomina:HorasExtras").Remove()
doc.Root.Element("nomina:Nomina").Attribute("DATO").Remove()
doc.Save(_xml2)
```

but is not working.

Would be nice if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        doc.Descendants.Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = ("Incapacidades")).Remove()
        doc.Descendants.Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = ("HorasExtras")).Remove()
        doc.Descendants.Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = ("Nomina")).Remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `XNamespace` and element local-name to reference element in namespace. For example, assuming namespace prefix `nomina` was declared as follow in your actual XML :

```
xmlns:nomina="foo"
```

Then you can find `HorasExtras` element, which prefixed with `nomina`, and remove it using the following :

```
Dim nomina As XNamespace = "foo"
doc.Root.Element(nomina + "HorasExtras").Remove()
```